# How to deal with a period in the middle of my quotation

Tags: periods, quoting

I don't know how to deal with the period in this quotation (or similar quotations where a period appears in the middle). Is my version 1 below acceptable or do I need to break it down (as in 2)?

1. Stanley thought that his and Zero’s situation was “more than a coincidence. It had to be destiny.”
2. Stanley thought that his and Zero's situation was "more than a coincidence." He thought that "It had to be destiny."

My instinct says 1 is okay, but I'm not sure. I'd be grateful for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

As it's a quotation, why break it up? 1) seems correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is to avoid the issue :

> Stanley thought that his and Zero’s situation was no mere coincidence:
>   "It had to be destiny.”

That would be my first choice. Or you can dish the quotation out in two servings:

> Stanley thought that his and Zero’s situation was "more than a
>   coincidence"; he thinks (or says) that it "had to be destiny”.

Or you can use brackets to indicate a minor change and ellipsis to indicate  omission of irrelevant matter, but this can add unnecessary clutter:

> Stanley thought that his and Zero’s situation was "more than a
>   coincidence ... [it] had to be  destiny.”

Comment: The OP already offered his own suggestion as to how to avoid the issue.

Comment: @Peter Shor: So what? I've suggested something different.  His workaround has a capital letter in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure both 1 and 2 are correct.

2 may *possibly* err in capitalizing "It," as apparently quotations are supposed to start with a lowercase letter when "used as a syntactical part of a sentence" (*[Questions on Citation](http://www.ncsu.edu/ncsu/grammar/Cite3.html)*, North Carolina State University Online Writing Lab; this page is itself actually citing *The Chicago Manual of Style* here).
The *Manual* gives an example with "that":

> With another aphorism, he reminded his reader that "experience keeps a
>   dear school, but fools will learn in no other"—an observation as true
>   today as then.

But in another place on the web, I found the following, apparently conflicting advice:

> If you are using the word "that" to introduce a quotation, do not also
>   use a comma. These two sentences show the two options.
>
> James Loewen states that "Socialism is repugnant to most Americans"
>   (33).
>
> James Loewen states, "Socialism is repugnant to most Americans" (33).

This example is from "[Punctuating Quotations](https://www.ivcc.edu/stylebooks/stylebook7.aspx?id=14670)," in the Stylebook for Illinois Valley Community College.  Note that here, a capital letter is used after "that." I'm not sure what the reason for the difference is; either these are two different acceptable styles, or one source is wrong, or there is a subtle difference between the grammar of these sentences that I'm missing.

But that's a bit of an aside. Sentence 1 seems to be grammatically correct, and it also sounds better to me; I would go with that. I do see why you had doubts about it, though... it's a little odd that the quotation begins in the middle of one sentence, but then the sentence ends before the quotation does. I'll try to find a source that explicitly mentions this kind of situation; I haven't been able to yet, but my instinct, like yours, tells me that it's OK.

If you decide not to use 1, I wouldn't use 2 but 3:

3. Stanley thought that his and Zero’s situation was “more than a coincidence," that it "had to be destiny.”

Comment: Isn't a conjunction required after comma after coincidence? I don't think you need to repeat "**that**" before it. I think "*a destiny*" works better than *destiny*.

Comment: @Rathony: you can't change the wording of a quotation. Besides, "destiny" is fine here and doesn't need an article.

Comment: Why do you think  you can't change the wording of a quotation? that is not quoted.